# PHP scandir not working for relative path

Tags: php, path, scandir

I have a folder called `images` in my current directory but when I try to run the code below I get the following error:

`PHP Warning:  scandir(../images,../images): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\dev\php\recolor_png\dir.php on line 4`

```
<?php
$dir = "../images";

$a = scandir($dir);

print_r($a);
```

I've tried every variation of the path I can think of (`images, /images/, "images", 'images'` etc. but no joy.

`var_dump (is_dir('/images'));` also gives `false`

Please help?

Comment: What prints var_dump(__ DIR __ . '/images');? Is it the right path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use `__DIR__` constant

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "/images";
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm running PHP from notepad++ with `cmd /k php -f &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;` and when I use `$dir = "./";` it shows me the notepad++ directory. Is this how I should usually deal with relative paths, or is it an npp quirk?

Comment: Yes, this how I should usually deal with relative paths. This is not a npp quirck. It happens because cmd opens with npp working dir.

Answer (score 2):

I think your **$dir**  is not correct.you can use

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "/images";
```

or

```
$dir = "./images";
```

Both are working. If its not working show me your image folder structure.